# Angular, ngx-spinner doesn't work inside directive

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend, angular-directive

I have directive element to append spinner in some components

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import { NgxSpinnerComponent, NgxSpinnerService } from "ngx-spinner";

@Directive({
    selector: 'ap-spinner'
})
export class SpinnerDirective implements OnInit {
@Input() show: boolean;

constructor(private ngxSpinnerService: NgxSpinnerService, private ele: ElementRef) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.ele.nativeElement.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",
    `<ngx-spinner type="ball-scale-multiple" [fullScreen]="false" size="small" style="width: 100px;" bdColor="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)"> Loading ... </ngx-spinner>`)
    this.ngxSpinnerService.show();
}

}
```

and inside component.html i used

```
<ap-spinner show="showSpinner"></ap-spinner>
```

but it show "Loading ... " and spinner does not running

Comment: Have you tried `<ap-spinner [show]="showSpinner"></ap-spinner>`?

Comment: yes and did not work , it doesn't related